# What shortcut am i missing? (Matrix diagonalization and exponents)

Tags: linear-algebra

We diagonalized $A$ and found $A^n$

$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}-2&2&1\\0&1&-2\\1&0&2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&9^n\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{2}{9}&\frac{2}{9}&\frac{1}{9}\\\frac{4}{9}&\frac{5}{9}&-\frac{2}{9}\\\frac{1}{9}&-\frac{2}{9}&\frac{2}{9}\end{bmatrix}$

After that, we expressed $v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\-4\end{bmatrix}$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $A$

$v = -\frac{10}{9}v_1 + \frac{1}{9}v_2 - \frac{13}{9}v_3$

Now we are asked to compute $u=A^n \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\-4\end{bmatrix}$

Textbook says that $u=9^n\left(-\frac{13}{9}v_3\right)$

What shortcut am i missing? I was ready to do the computation directly

Comment: Probably just a mistake in arithmetic, yours or theirs. Check your work, carefully. Calculate $Av$ and see which answer it agrees with.

Comment: Can you include the matrix $A$? Then one can check the diagonalization, too.

Comment: And what is your result? Doesn't it agree with the text book? For this, too, include the original matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$$u=A^nv=A^{n-1}(Av)=A^{n-1}(\frac{-10}{9}\lambda_1v_1+\frac{1}{9}\lambda_2v_2 - \frac{13}{9}\lambda_3v_3)$$

If you see your diagonalized matrix the $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$. $$u=-\frac{13}{9}\lambda_3A^{n-1}v_3=-\frac{13}{9}\lambda_3^nv_3$$

Comment: And $\lambda_3^n=9^n$, actually, or not?

Comment: @Sona_sqrt Thank you!